# How fetch data from REST API and populate an array with JSON data in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rest

I am trying to populate `matches:[]` with JSON data from a REST API. I am not able to fetch() data from REST API.

JSON response of REST API:
[image]

In main.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            matches:[]
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('api/matches')
        .then(res => this.setState({matches}, () => console.log('Matches fetched...', matches)));
    }

    render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4" styles="background-color:lavender;">{this.state.matches[0].season}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4" styles="background-color:lavenderblush;">{this.state.matches[5].season}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-4" styles="background-color:lavender;">{this.state.matches[8].season}</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

I am later populating the JSON data into bootstrap to display it in grid system but I get error for these lines saying TypeError for below lines:

```
this.state.matches[0].season
this.state.matches[5].season
this.state.matches[8].season
```

Comment: did u checked in network tab with XHR?What is the response for this API

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN https://imgur.com/a/H0Krf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing `matches[0]`, `matches[5]` or `matches[8]` without fetching from your API is going to break your app.

I suggest changing the `render` method to something like:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  if (this.state.matches.length === 0) {
    return <div>There aren't any matches !</div>
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4" styles="background-color:lavender;">{this.state.matches[0].season}</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4" styles="background-color:lavenderblush;">{this.state.matches[5].season}</div>
        <div class="col-lg-4" styles="background-color:lavender;">{this.state.matches[8].season}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

After you start `fetch`, you still need to parse the response to the format you want (`JSON` in this case). Ony after that, you'll be able to use `setState`:

```
state = {
  matches: [],
  loading: true
};
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('/api/matches')
    .then(res => res.json()) // It resolves the promise with a JSON object
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res) // make sure that matches is `res` directly or a neste object within `res` object
      this.setState({
        matches: res,
        loading: false
      })
    })
}
```

Should you need more information about `fetch` and how it works, I recommend reading [David Walsh's](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch) explanation.

Comment: I am getting matches un defined.

Comment: @stonerock try to `console.log(res)` before you set state to check whether the results from the api are there or not.

Comment: Now I am getting res not defined

Comment: @stonerock I've just updated my answer. Hope it helps now :)

Comment: I think I am not getting JSON data in console also getting `this.state.matches[0]` as undefined

Comment: Now it works fine. I had added `/` as said by @Shobhit in `fetch(/api/matches)` which I removed and now works like a charm thank you.

Comment: Instead this line ` matches: res` can I use it like this -> {matches}

Comment: Yes, as long as `res` is the exact `matches` object you are expecting it to be :)

Comment: @merscocarlin When I comment out the if statement in render I again get the same error undefined also no JSON data is logged in console why does this happen ?

Comment: @stonerock It's because `matches` is empty. How can you access an array at position `0` if it is empty?

Comment: So initially the array matches is empty but after sometime it should get populated as soon as the fetch request is made then why does it throw error that `this.state.matches[0].season` is undefined.

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(this.state.matches)` in the render method to make sure it has values?

Comment: No I did not logged it in console but I have seen many tutorials online but in it they do not use conditional statements in render function. Can you please suggest me some tutorials/resources where I can learn about this concept.

Comment: @stonerock Sure. I suggest starting from ReactJS' tutorial about conditional rendering: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: I am getting error sometimes saying Syntax error JSON.parse and if I refresh the page it does not show the error why is this happening see screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/aJZtW https://imgur.com/a/HonmQ  Why does this happen should I remove the if statement `this.state.matches.length === 0` I think this is causing error.

Comment: whenever I make any changes and I open `localhost:3000` it shows `Loading...` and when I refresh the page it then shows the json data on webpage why is this happening

Answer (score -2):

I can see that you've not called the api route correctly. Assuming you did setup the api in a way as below -

```
app.get('/api/matches', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ matches }));
});
```

I your react code, you can call the api as -

```
fetch('/api/matches).then()
```

Notice the `/`.

Hope this helps? Do let me know otherwise.

Comment: why do I need to add these lines `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');`` res.send(JSON.stringify({ matches }));` as it already sends JSON data to REST API endpoint localhost:5000/api/matches

Comment: No need of using `/` in `api/matches` as I am using proxy -> `localhost:5000`